# closer browser window.close not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to close the browser window using javascript on button click this is what I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenMyWin() {
        window.open('', '_self');
        window.close();
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="OpenMyWin();"/>
```

and also I tried the alternate way

`btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.close();");` and

`btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:OpenMyWin();");`

I also tried this

`<script type="text/javascript">
        function closeWindow() {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
            alert("This will close the window");
            window.open('', '_self');
            window.close();
        }
    </script>`

Still I am unable to close my browser can some one help me I need the close event which should work on all browsers

Answer (score 0):

As you have type it you can only change it to this and its working:

```
function OpenMyWin() {
    window.open('', '_self').close();
}
```

I tested on google chrome and its working, but is not working on mozilla.

Comment: @User I do not know, they may have disable this function for security reasons.

Comment: @User I think that is better to use inside "windows" that you can control them. Windows made by divs and iframe.